# django - persisting an email to database to be able to send it later?

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

In my django project I want to store an email in the database to be able to retrieve it later and send it. I'm implementing a throttling mechanism for sending emails to many users.

I thought it would be as easy as storing 'to, from, subject, body' but then I realized there are attachments, multipart emails, etc, there is at least two classes `EmailMessage` and `EmailMultiAlternatives`... too many variables and options!

I thought of storing the raw email that one gets with the `message()` method, but then not sure how to construct the email back. Also tried `pickle` but got `can't pickle lock objects`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django models, signals and email sending delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349483/django-models-signals-and-email-sending-delay)

Comment: I take it as a suggestion of using django-mailer to implement throttling. However the question itself is very different.

Comment: This sounds like a job for celery, but you'll still need a way to serialize the messages unless you serialize at a higher level.

Comment: I just tried pickling an EmailMessage with an attachment and that worked.

Comment: (aha, I tried pickling it without a Django config!)

Comment: yes the question is how to serialize a message

Comment: ...I meant it worked for me because I had no `self.connection` due to no `settings.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess based on your `can't pickle lock objects` message that you may be trying to `pickle` your objects with the default SMTP `connection` included.

Try it without it - grepping through the source it is the `smtp` module that has a `self._lock`.  Pass `connection=None` to the constructor of the messages.

On Django 1.9, this works for me (Python2):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
import pickle

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
    ['bcc@example.com'],
    reply_to=['another@example.com'],
    headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
    connection=None,
)

email.attach("foo", [l for l in open(__file__)], 'text')

print len(pickle.dumps(email))

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to], connection=None)
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

print len(pickle.dumps(msg))
```

According to the Django code in `messages.py`, later when you call `send()` it will attempt to use `get_connection()` from `django.core.mail` to get your default connection if `EmailMessage.connection` is `None`.

....Alternatively, if you want to use `json`, this also worked with `connection=None`:

```
import json                                                            
print json.dumps(msg.__dict__)                                         
print json.dumps(email.__dict__)
```

This means you could fairly easily write a `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` to serialize/deserialize your objects as well by basically using the `__dict__` of the object.

More on JSON:

As I showed above, encoding the `__dict__` makes the encoding easy.  You could do `msg.__dict__ = json.load(...)`, but what makes it difficult is the `EmailMessage` object must be created before you change its values.  So you could initialize `msg` with an `EmailMessage` that has dummy values, and then assign the `__dict__`, or decode the `JSON` and construct the object explicitly by passing the arguments (...and functions) stored in the JSON to the constructor.  This requires you to know the internals, though.

I'd go with `pickle`, although there are security implications.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606858/pickle-not-safe-or-fast) covers some other alternatives as well.

Comment: what if I m not the one constructing the email, I still can set connection to None, right? will try that and see. Thanks!!!

Comment: Ah, you're downstream?  Yeah, you could just do `msg.connection = None` to unset it.

Comment: yes, I'm writing a custom email backend that stores the emails and sends them later. Thanks! it works :D

Comment: hey how would you load the object back up with json? I 'm runnng into the following error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556269/importerror-no-module-named-copy-reg-pickle

Comment: @MartinMassera You're reading and writing in binary?  `"wb"`?

Comment: no, as text. I see that the bug is in text mode (and would be solved with binary) but it just seems it would be better to do it in json if possible.